# Compare 2 text files unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix, diff

I have 2 text files in below format

```
field1                         : test1
field2                         : test2
field3                         : test3
field4                         : test4
```

and File 2 as :--

```
 field1 : test1
 field2 : test2
 field3 : test3
 field4 : test4
```

I am trying to compare the files and output as "All records Matched" if everything matches and if it doesn't then "Data Mismatch for **field name**  "

I tried using diff to do basic match by ignoring white space but it is not happening.

```
diff -byw 1.txt 2.txt
```

Can someone help me with same ?

Regards.

Comment: What does "it is not happening" mean exactly? What is the output of diff? Have you tried -b?

Comment: yes I tried -b  . It shows all lines as mismatch

Comment: try -E ignore the tab expansion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having mismatch as there is space at start of each line in 2nd file. Remove the space using sed

```
 sed -i 's/^ *//' 2.txt
```

and now compare using diff -b it will work fine.

Comment: Thank you :) .. it worked . Can you tell me how to print sucess or failure based in exact match

Answer (score 2):

In shell, you can use `$?` to check output status of previous command. `$?` holds 0 if last command was successful with exit status 0, other wise. You can check `$?` value and print statements accordingly.
Input files

```
cat 1.txt 
field1                         : test1
field2                         : test2
field3                         : test3
field4                         : test4
cat 2.txt 
field1 : test1
field2 : test2
field3 : test3
field4 : test4
```

Commands below

```
   > diff -bE 1.txt 2.txt 
   > if [ $? -eq 0 ];then echo SUCCESSFUL; else echo FAIL; fi
```

Output

```
SUCCESSFUL
```

If files data do not match [Leading spaces in 2.txt]

```
diff -bE 1.txt 2.txt 
1c1
< field1                         : test1
---
>  field1 : test1
3c3
< field3                         : test3
---
>  field3 : test3

if [ $? -eq 0 ];then echo SUCCESSFUL; else echo FAIL; fi
```

OutPut

```
FAIL
```